# how to append the table but with condition and re rank the table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

for example

```
user          Top Genre
a             Horror    
b             Romance
```

and I have the contentbased table for for genre :

for example

```
Genre         Rec        Rank
Horror        Action      1     
Horror        Comedy      2
Romance       Asian       1
Romance       Comedy      2
```

i want to join table so the output will be :

for example

```
User     Rec        Rank
a        Horror      1  
a        Action      2
a        Comedy      3
b        Romance     1  
b        Asian       2
b        Comedy      3
```

how to process two tables so that the output is like table above with pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `right` join and add same DataFrame with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns, sorting by both columns and last add `1` to `Rank`:

```
df11 = df1.rename(columns={'Top Genre':'Genre'})
df = df11.merge(df2, how='right').append(df11.assign(Rec = df11['Genre'], Rank=0))
df = df.sort_values(['user','Rank'], ignore_index=True)
df['Rank'] +=1
print (df)
  user    Genre      Rec  Rank
0    a   Horror   Horror     1
1    a   Horror   Action     2
2    a   Horror   Comedy     3
3    b  Romance  Romance     1
4    b  Romance    Asian     2
5    b  Romance   Comedy     3
```